# LINQ request many-to-many

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many

I have the following tables

```
Users
 - ID
 - FirstName
 - LastName

MultiplyItems
 - ItemID
 - Title

UserMultiplyItems
 - UserID
 - ItemID
```

I have a variable

```
List<int> delegateList = {1, 3, 5};
```

where 1, 3, 5 are ItemID

I want to select all users, where at least one ItemID linked selectable user.
I try the following:

```
        var result = from i in _dbContext.Users
                     where 
                     ((delegateList == null) || i.MultiplyItems.Any(p=> delegateList.Any(a => a == p.ItemID)))

                     select new UserModel()
                     {
                         ....
                     };
```

but it does not work. error:

> Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'.
>   Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are
>   supported.

How to do it correctly?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this one:

```
var filteredUsers = delegateList == null 
    ? _dbContext.Users
    : _dbContext.Users.Where(user => user.MultiplyItems
        .Any(item => delegateList.Contains(item.Id)));

var result = filteredUsers.Select(user => new UserModel
        {
            //the UserModel initialization
        });
```

You should not check the following line inside the query:

```
delegateList == null
```

It is translated to SQL, and SQL has no idea about what is List and how to compare it with null.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var result = from i in _dbContext.Users
    from mi in i.multiplyItems
    select new yourClass();

    if(delegateList!=null)
    {
       result = result.Where(delegateList.contains(mi.ItemID));
    }

    result.ToList();
```

I dont have visual studio open to test, but it should be a lot like that.

Comment: thank you, but how to check on delegateList=null (then ignore this part)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you wanted, but i thought its better to try and help.

This will output all users from the Users Table where the ItemID is contained in the delegateList. The magic lays in the Contains operator you can get elements from list a contained in list b

```
var selection = from a in db.UserMultiplyItems
                from b in db.Users
                where delegateList.Contains(a.ItemID) && a.UserID == b.ID
                select b;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing it to:

```
var result = from u in _dbContext.Users
where 
((delegateList == null) || u.MultiplyItems.Any( mi => delegateList.Contains(mi.ItemID)))

select new UserModel()
{
 ....
};
```

Note I've also renamed your "i" and "p" things to "u" and "mi" to make it easier to read.

Comment: Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you could not use LINQ at all and just stick with lambda expressions:

```
List<UserModel> usersWithItems =
    context
    .Users
    .Where(u => u.MultiplyItems.Any(mi => (delegateList == null) || (delegateList.Contains(mi.ItemID))))
    .Select(um => (new UserModel() { ...  } ) )
    .ToList();
```

Which personally I prefer, it means you don't need to know linq at all.